# Docker does not start if the home directory is renamed on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I have renamed Mac Os user and home directory by https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548

After this Docker Desctop doesn't work([error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0dls.png)). I have tried to reinstall Docker Desktop several times, but the error is the same. Docker Desktop is trying to create a directory under my old user directory which doesn't exist. I don't understand where docker gets this directory. How to solve it?

Here is my users directories
❯ ls /Users

Shared   klaipher

Comment: To fix this run `rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/`, In settings.json caches your previous home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in docker settings, `docker -> settings -> resources -> Disk image location` , images are stored inside your home directory. Removing this directory resolves this issue.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an add on to UberHans answer:
Run both commands:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
```

and

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/
```

Note that all the stored images and containers will be deleted❗️